# Combine 3 IF statements into one line (w/Index-Match)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to have all 3 formulas combined into one single line. I'm having a hard time simplifying this without getting an error:

```
=IF(C2="Products", IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), "Not Found")
=IF(C2="MenuCategory", IFERROR(INDEX('Products Category List'!$B:$B,MATCH(E2, 'Products Category List'!$A:$A,0)), "Not Found"), "Not Found")
=IF(C2="Ingredient", IFERROR(INDEX('Ingredients List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'Ingredients List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), "Not Found")
```

I thought I could just separate each with a comma in one line, but it won't let me do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to "nest" these `if` formulas, so that the third parameter instead of being "Not Found" is the next `If` formula. Something like:

```
=IF(C2="Products", IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), IF(C2="MenuCategory", IFERROR(INDEX('Products Category List'!$B:$B,MATCH(E2, 'Products Category List'!$A:$A,0)), "Not Found"), IF(C2="Ingredient", IFERROR(INDEX('Ingredients List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'Ingredients List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), "Not Found")))
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this, thank you for your help!